# MacOs Ventura PHP driver SQL Server need signature

Tags: php, sql, macos, driver

i have macOs Ventura.
I have installed PHP 8.2.6 and have signature this. After I have installed sql server driver but PHP not charge it because it's need a signature.

```
[Sun Jul 23 19:22:54.943269 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6278] AH00173: SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
Failed loading /usr/local/opt/php/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so:  dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so, 0x0009): tried: '/usr/local/opt/php/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so' (code signature in <021DB432-08C5-30C1-A1E8-E4F821E1F1C7> '/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.2.8/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so' not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/opt/php/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/opt/php/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so' (code signature in <021DB432-08C5-30C1-A1E8-E4F821E1F1C7> '/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.2.8/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so' not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.), '/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.2.8/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so' (code signature in <021DB432-08C5-30C1-A1E8-E4F821E1F1C7> '/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.2.8/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so' not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.2.8/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.2.8/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so' (code signature in <021DB432-08C5-30C1-A1E8-E4F821E1F1C7> '/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.2.8/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so' not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.)
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20220829/sqlsrv.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20220829/sqlsrv.so, 0x0009): tried: '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20220829/sqlsrv.so' (code signature in &lt;4FDF245B-D4D4-3988-A6B3-A6783BE8DB7D&gt; '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20220829/sqlsrv.so' not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20220829/sqlsrv.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20220829/sqlsrv.so' (code signature in &lt;4FDF245B-D4D4-3988-A6B3-A6783BE8DB7D&gt; '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20220829/sqlsrv.so' not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.)), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20220829/sqlsrv.so.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20220829/sqlsrv.so.so, 0x0009): tried: '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20220829/sqlsrv.so.so' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20220829/sqlsrv.so.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20220829/sqlsrv.so.so' (no such file))) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20220829/pdo_sqlsrv.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20220829/pdo_sqlsrv.so, 0x0009): tried: '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20220829/pdo_sqlsrv.so' (code signature in &lt;85AD7E41-CA05-3EA6-9914-4FC4BE087D94&gt; '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20220829/pdo_sqlsrv.so' not valid for use in process: mapped file has no Team ID and is not a platform binary (signed with custom identity or adhoc?)), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20220829/pdo_sqlsrv.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20220829/pdo_sqlsrv.so' (code signature in &lt;85AD7E41-CA05-3EA6-9914-4FC4BE087D94&gt; '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20220829/pdo_sqlsrv.so' not valid for use in process: mapped file has no Team ID and is not a platform binary (signed with custom identity or adhoc?))), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20220829/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20220829/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so, 0x0009): tried: '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20220829/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20220829/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20220829/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so' (no such file))) in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Jul 23 19:22:55.026518 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6278] AH00163: Apache/2.4.56 (Unix) PHP/8.2.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 23 19:22:55.026594 2023] [core:notice] [pid 6278] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

How resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance.